# Is $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4+1}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am required to decide whether the following complex function:

$$f(z)=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{3}z^{j}}{\sum_{j=0}^{7}z^j}$$

is analytic or not. I simplied $f$ such that:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4+1}$$

I know that $f$ is analytic at $z=z_0\iff f$ satisfies *Cauchy-Riemann* equations at a neighborhood of $z=z_0$. The problem is that in order to use CR equations, I need to find $\Re{(f(z))}$ and $\Im{(f(z))}$, and that seems algebraically ugly here. So I'm here to ask if you have an easier solution to the problem, or that my only shot is substituting $z=x+iy$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have *any* other facts about analytic functions?  (If you only have one fact, that's the only one you get to use.)

Comment: You can always do partial fraction decomposition first before substituting $z=x+iy$. Do you know of the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: If a function is analytic at $z=a$, then it is bounded in a neighbourhood of $a$. Show that $f$ is unbounded near any $a$ satisfying $a^4=-1$.

Comment: Any ratio of polynomials $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, with $q(0)\neq 0$, is analytic in a neighbourhood of the origin. The radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series is exactly the distance of the roots of $q$ from the origin.

Answer (score 1):

It is not defined at points $z$ with $z^{4}+1=0$ and it does not even have a finite limit as $z$ tends to such a point. On $\mathbb C\setminus \{z:z^{4}=-1\}$ it is analytic because it is ratio of two analytic functions with the denominator $\neq 0$.

Comment: This is indeed true, but we don't know if OP is allowed to assume so in solving this question or has to use C-R equations.